# Collecting like term of an expression in Sympy

Tags: python, python-2.7, math, sympy, polynomials

I am currently dealing with functions of more than one variable and need to collect like terms in an attempt to simplify an expression.

Say the expression is written as follows:

```
x = sympy.Symbol('x')
y = sympy.Symbol('y')
k = sympy.Symbol('k')
a = sympy.Symbol('a')

z = k*(y**2*(a + x) + (a + x)**3/3) - k((2*k*y*(a + x)*(n - 1)*(-k*(y**2*(-a + x) + (-a + x)**3/3) + k*(y**2*(a + x) + (a + x)**3/3)) + y)**2*(-a + k*(n - 1)*(y**2 + (a + x)**2)*(-k*(y**2*(-a + x)))))
zEx = z.expand()
print type(z)
print type(zEx)
```

EDIT: Formatting to add clarity and changed  the expression z to make the problem easier to understand.

Say `z` contains so many terms, that sifting through them by eye. and selecting the appropriate terms, would take an unsatisfactory amount of time.

I want to collect all of the terms which are **ONLY** a multiple of a**1. I do not care for quadratic or higher powers of a, and I do not care for terms which do not contain a.

The type of `z` and `zEx` return the following:

```
print type(z)
print type(zEx)
>>>
<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
<class 'sympy.core.mul.Mul'>
```

Does anyone know how I can collect the terms which are a multiple of `a` , not a^0 or a^2?

tl'dr

Where z(x,y) with constants a and k described by `z` and `zEx` and their type(): How can one remove all non-`a` terms from `z` AND remove all quadratic or higher terms of `a` from the expression? Such that what is left is **only** the terms which contain a unity power of `a`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to the other answers given, you can also use `collect` as a dictionary.

```
print(collect(zEx,a,evaluate=False)[a])
```

yields the expression

```
k*x**2 + k*y**2
```

Answer (score 2):

In the end it is just an one-liner. @asmeurer brought me on the right track (check the comments below this post). Here is the code; explanations can be found below:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
import sys

x, y, k, a = symbols('x y k a')

# modified string: I added a few terms
z = x*(k*a**9) + (k**1)*x**2 - k*a**8 + y*x*(k**2) + y*(x**2)*k**3 + x*(k*a**1) - k*a**3 + y*a**5

zmod = Add(*[argi for argi in z.args if argi.has(a)])
```

Then `zmod` is

```
a**9*k*x - a**8*k + a**5*y - a**3*k + a*k*x
```

So let's look at this more carefully:

```
z.args
```

is just a collection of all individual terms in your expression (please note, that also the sign is parsed which makes things easier):

```
(k*x**2, a**5*y, -a**3*k, -a**8*k, a*k*x, a**9*k*x, k**2*x*y, k**3*x**2*y)
```

In the list comprehension you then select all the terms that contain an `a` using the function `has`. All these terms can then be glued back together using `Add` which gives you the desired output.

**EDIT**

The above returns all all the expressions that contain an `a`. If you only want to filter out the expressions that contain `a` with unity power, you can use [`collect`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#collect) and `Mul`:

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import parse_expr
import sys

x, y, k, a = symbols('x y k a')

z2 = x**2*(k*a**1) + (k**1)*x**2 - k*a**8 + y*x*(k**2) + y*(x**2)*k**3 + x*k*a - k*a**3 + y*a**1

zc = collect(z2, a, evaluate=False)
zmod2 = Mul(zc[a], a)
```

then `zmod2` is

```
a*(k*x**2 + k*x + y)
```

and `zmod2.expand()`

```
a*k*x**2 + a*k*x + a*y
```

which is correct.

With the updated `z` you provide I run:

```
z3 =  k*(y**2*(a + x) + (a + x)**3/3) - k((2*k*y*(a + x)*(n - 1)*(-k*(y**2*(-a + x) + (-a + x)**3/3) + k*(y**2*(a + x) + (a + x)**3/3)) + y)**2*(-a + k*(n - 1)*(y**2 + (a + x)**2)*(-k*(y**2*(-a + x)))))
zc3 = collect(z3.expand(), a, evaluate=False)
zmod3 = Mul(zc3[a], a)
```

and then obtain for `zmod3.expand()`:

```
a*k*x**2 + a*k*y**2
```

Is this the result you were looking for?

PS: Thanks to @asmeurer for all these helpful comments!

Comment: If you're using strings to manipulate sympy expressions you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @asmeurer: As far as I understood the question, the OP wants to filter all the terms in `z` that contain a parameter `a`. Converting it to a string first was the only way I could get this done since iterating over `z.args` does not allow(?) to check whether `a` is in the element. The `collect` seems not suitable for that either but maybe I use it in a wrong manner. Maybe you could extend your answer, using `z` like I defined it and try to get the same result as I did without converting it to a string first!? I am always glad to broaden my knowledge :)

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Splitting it into a string seems to work well when the expression is all positive. But what if there are negative terms in the expression? I don't think it wouldsplit the terms correctly. 

How could I go about doing this is everyother term was negative?

Comment: If ALL of them are negative you have to do `zstr.split('-')` and `' - '.join(res)`.  If there are both `+` and `-`, it becomes a bit trickier. I could try to update the post later on. But according to @asmeurer and at least one other person that is not the way to go - it got even downvoted although it does the job.

Comment: @user2970710: I updated the code. It now also works with mixed signs. Let me know if that answers your question.

Comment: @Cleb you can check if an expression contains a subexpression using `has`, like `term.has(a)`.

Comment: @asmeurer: Ok, thanks, I did not know that. But how would you then glue these terms back together using the appropriate sign for each term?

Comment: In SymPy, subtraction is represented as multiplication by -1. So `x - y` is the same as `Add(x, Mul(-1, y))`. Hence if you split it by args the sign is already on the terms, so to put them back together you just need to do `Add(*terms)`.

Comment: @asmeurer: Thanks so much for those comments! I updated my code; hope it is correct now... Could learn a lot which is worth your downvote ;)

Comment: @Cleb I removed the downvote. I would just remove the old answer, though. It will still be visible in the edit history.

Comment: I have also learned a lot about how to ask a question concisely on this site ^^ Your method workd well @Cleb. However it seems to collect all terms which contain `a`, as opposed to ONLY terms with a unity power of a.

I only wish to "glue together" the terms which contain a**1. Whereas your method provides me with a**9, a**8, a**5 etc.

Apologies for not making this stunningly clear in the first place! I really appreciate your efforts and I think you're pretty close to cracking it :D Hope this helps.

Comment: @user2970710: I updated my post once again; please check the EDIT. Hope that this is the result you were looking for?! :)

Answer (score 1):

To iterate over the terms of an expression use `expr.args`.

I'm unclear what `a` is supposed to be, but the [`collect` function](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#collect) may do what you want.

Comment: Sorry. a should have been defined as another variable: 

    a = sympy.Symbol('a')